# Append data to html table

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to add more data to the table below using JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/style.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

      <br><br><br><br><br>

      <input type="text" id="personName" autofocus>
      <button type="button" onclick="addData();">Append Information</button>   <br><br><br><br><br>

      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Client Name</th>
        </tr>


          <tr>
            <td>James Bond 007</td>
          </tr>

          <div id="addDataHere">

          </div>

      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

### style.js Used is below:

```
function addData(){
  var personName = document.getElementById("personName").value;
  //console.log(personName);

  var getOlderInformation = document.getElementById("addDataHere").innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("addDataHere").innerHTML = getOlderInformation + "<tr><td>" + personName + "</tr></td>";



}
```

### Expected Output Results:

> #### Client Names
>  James Bond 007
>  Tom Cruise
>  ............
>  ............
>  ............
>  ............

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started.

```js
function addData() {
    var personName = document.getElementById("personName").value;
    var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
    var newCell = document.createElement("td");
    newCell.innerHTML = personName;
    newRow.append(newCell);
    document.getElementById("rows").appendChild(newRow);
    document.getElementById("personName").value = '';
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="personName" autofocus>
    <button type="button" onclick="addData();">Append Information</button> <br><br><br><br><br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Client Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="rows">
            <tr>
                <td>James Bond 007</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

You were on the correct path, but an important note is that you were trying to use a div inside of a table. A table has very specific structure that has to be matched if you want it to render properly.

You are able to put div elements inside of a td or a th, but not inside of the table element itself. Check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Answer (score 1):

You can use an approach similar to what you are attempting: getting the `innerHTML`, appending some new html, and then replacing the innerHTML. But, you need to get the `innerHTML` of your `table` (not the element you nested inside of it).

For example (replaced your `button` `onclick` with an event listener).

```js
const personName = document.getElementById('personName');
const appendButton = document.getElementById('appendButton');
const nameTable = document.getElementById('nameTable');
appendButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let content = nameTable.innerHTML;
  content += '<tr><td>' + personName.value + '</td></tr>';
  nameTable.innerHTML = content;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="personName" autofocus>
<button type="button" id="appendButton">Append Information</button>
<table id="nameTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Client Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>James Bond 007</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Depending on the complexity of what you are doing, it may be faster to go the `createElement` / `appendChild` route suggested in the other answers if you also use use `createDocumentFragment`. Another example:

```js
appendButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  const td = document.createElement('td');
  td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(personName.value));
  tr.appendChild(td);
  frag.appendChild(tr);
  nameTable.appendChild(frag);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="personName" autofocus>
<button type="button" id="appendButton">Append Information</button>
<table id="nameTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Client Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>James Bond 007</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a list to match what you need here's the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Home Page</title>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="personName" autofocus>
  <button type="button" onclick="addData();">Append Information</button> 
    <p>Client Name</p>
  <ul id="mylist">
        <li>James Bond 007</li>
    </ul>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the use adddata() function code like this 
`function addData(){

```
    var mylist=document.getElementById("mylist");
    var personName=document.getElementById("personName").value;
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(personName);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    mylist.appendChild(node);
}`
```

I hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use appendchild. Check this out for some
Good examples https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp .  You want to loop through the data adding a row to a table , one row at a time

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at it now. @Simon Curtis

Comment: Also, check out YouTube too. I’ve seen this sort of thing a few times in different beginner tutorials . Good luck!